# Phonegap: FileTransfer vs Ajax?

Tags: cordova

What are the main differences between sending file to a server via Ajax and the FileTransfer functionality in Phonegap?  Is one better than the other? Or are they essentially the same?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer
vs
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileTransfer object uses multipart/form-data to POST the data up to the server. Ajax uses UTF-8 to send the data up to the server using XHR.

Comment: could you possibly elaborate on what the functional difference is? what are the pros/cons? is one faster or more efficient? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can't send file with javascript or with jquery. You have to do a native app to access to the filesystem.

PhoneGap do that for you.

Comment: but you can ajax over the base64 encoded image, no? http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39539478/Upload%20an%20Image%20to%20a%20PHP%20Script

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage of AJAX is size. Since you have to use a BASE64 encoding of the file, it grows in size due to the limited set of characters of BASE64.